# PHP Generate an unique hash from an IPADDRESS

Tags: php, hash, ip, ip-address

I have a board and i want to disable registrations instead i want the users to be able to post freely with an unique ID based on their IPAddress

for example:

if "Joe" IP is 200.100.15.117, "Joe" nickname will become the hash function of 200.100.15.117

*if "Joe" IP changes he will get another ID, that doesn't matter, i only want one unique ID per IPAddress*

There are also two important things :

- unique ID must be 8 characters long
- hash should be secure, i don't want hackers be abble to crack my
  users IPaddresses

I thought in using an MD5 function and then trim it to 8 chars, but how unique is that ? is there a better way ?

Comment: wont work, ip does not equal person, one ip can be many people, one person many ip's. use a 'proper' user registration system.

Comment: Trimming an MD5 hash is never a good idea if you want unique values.
I would say it is never a good idea, period.

Comment: Instead of md5, you can use sha1 function, it provides much stronger security than md5 (it uses 40 bytes, instead of 32 in md5) and it is build-in PHP.

Comment: If you want to trim hash to 8 characters then you still need to check duplicates.

Comment: What i want to implement is something similar to 4chan/b/ has

Comment: just allow any one to post anything, that's going to be the end result anyway

Comment: You forget also the part that some networks have rotating IP's so "Joe" can work the next day on 200.100.18.145 for example. This means that your database will be littered with IP's that are all Joe's. I would suggest a registering procedure, even if you dont want it, and just keep track of IP's per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** According to OP comment on this answer.

Code below uses BC Math library to translate a MD5 hash into a Base-90 string. This converts a 32 char string into a 20 char one. This is far from desired 8 chars but it is the minimum string length using ASCII range (it is possible to increase the base to Base-94 by using chars `'` `"` `\` *`[space]`* but this does not affect to the string length and instead may cause problems while handling data).

```
$ip      = '200.100.15.117';
$hash    = md5($ip);
$chars16 = array(
    '0' => 0,  '1' => 1,  '2' => 2,  '3' => 3, '4' => 4,  '5' => 5,
    '6' => 6,  '7' => 7,  '8' => 8,  '9' => 9, 'a' => 10, 'b' => 11,
    'c' => 12, 'd' => 13, 'e' => 14, 'f' => 15
);
$base10 = '0';
for ($i = strlen($hash) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $base10 = bcadd($base10, bcmul($chars16[$hash[$i]], bcpow(16, $i)));
}
$chars   = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,;.:-_+*?!$%&@#~^=/<>[](){}`';
$base    = (string)strlen($chars);
$baseX   = '';
while (bccomp($base10, $base) === 1 || bccomp($base10, $base) === 0) {
    $baseX  = substr($chars, bcmod($base10, $base), 1) . $baseX;
    $base10 = preg_replace('/\.\d*$/', '', bcdiv($base10, $base));
}
$baseX = substr($chars, $base10, 1) . $baseX;
echo $baseX; // Shows: 1BS[JdZf/7J$J{ud&r5i
```

Comment: thanks for your reply :) but this will be easy reversible http://sami.on.eniten.com/hex2ip/ i don't want to expose my users, for that reason i want a hash, i am using a trimmed sha1 at the moment, hope i don't get too many collisions

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the ip address string to LONG(4 bytes) and do whatever you want next.

see the php function [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php).

Answer (score 1):

The thing with this is that you cant really diferentiate 2 persons on the same network, so if I post on there, and my dorm neighbour goes to the site, the site thinks he is me.

You should consider using cookies, these can easily be made unique, and AFAIK, can't be hacked remotely.

For the unique ID part, if you are storing the "users" in a database, you could just assign the primary key from your "user" table and use that in the cookie.

If it HAS to be 8 chars long, you could prepend 0's to the ID - e.g. 00000001, 00000002.... Atleast this way its unique, and 8 chars long-

Comment: Jeff is right. You can not trust on IPs to identify users. Use cookies instead. A session with long expiration time will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can salt the ip address, e.g.

```
$salt = "e45re%$#";
$ip = "200.111.123.111";
$hash = md5($ip.$salt);

$hash = substr($hash,0,8);
```